# Importing JParsec in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jparsec

I downloaded both the .jar file and the "source and documentation" zip archive from [the JParsec download section](http://jparsec.codehaus.org/Downloads). Somehow I failed to import the JParsec source code using the Eclipse IDE (and also to find any documentation). Can someone please explain how to import it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Java project and add the appropriate .jar file into the build path. You can also link the source file to the .jar file using the "Build Path" choice.

Answer (score 0):

The codehaus project is no longer active, jparsec is now hosted on [github](http://github.com/abailly/jparsec). If you clone the source code from there, you can import the project using the [maven plugin for Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), or alternatively do `mvm eclipse:eclipse` inside the project source tree and then open the project in Eclipse.